# Why can't insert "\textrm" in "xparse"?

Tags: xparse

I tested these codes in Texworks with Xelatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ProvideDocumentCommand\pH{\textrm{pH}}
\begin{document}
\pH~\num{5}.
\end{document}
```

The error is :
`! LaTeX cmd Error: Invalid argument type '\textrm ' in command '\pH'.`

So where was wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: You have omitted the mandaory argument to `\ProvideDocumentCommand` that gives the argumen type, `{}` here

Comment: tl;dr: On error stare at the documentation/command usage.

Comment: @user202729 Okay, I will do that in the future.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `{}` to specify the command takes no arguments

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\usepackage{xparse}% only needed with old latex releases
\ProvideDocumentCommand\pH{}{\textrm{pH}}
\begin{document}
\pH~\num{5}.
\end{document}
```